# Laravel relation between 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models Customer, Task, Staffs. Now task is realted to customer and also staff is related to customer. But there is no relation between staff and task. How can i get all the three records from one ORM.

relationship

```
/*staff*/  /**have pivot table 'staff_customer' **/
public function customers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Customer');
}


/*customer*/
public function staffs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Staff');
}
public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany('Task');
}


/*task*/  /** has cutomer_id in table*/
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
}
```

I have tasks filtered by dates already. I need its customers and the staffs related to those customers.

```
$tasks = Task::Where(...)->with('customer')->with('staffs')->get();
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on how the tables are related to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to base your query on `Customer` since this is the model containing both relations. I believe something like this would work:

```
Customer::with('staffs', 'tasks')->where('tasks.field', $value)->get();
```

*Edit*

I believe this should be possible as well:

```
Task::where( ... )->with('customer', 'customer.staffs')->get();
```

Comment: How to use variable in that where `whereRaw('? between tasks.rem_date and tasks.due_date', [$today])`  will this work

Comment: @DevAbel Have you tried? I don't understand why you would use `whereRaw` though, just use `where`?

Comment: @DevAbel You can't do that, there are separate DB queries, so you can't reference another table there, unless you use joins.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That's not true. Eloquent will do a join statement when you're eager loading relations in your ORM code. So it is perfectly possible to query `tasks`, `customers` and `staffs` tables in either of my examples.

Comment: Ronni Interesting... Show me example pls ;) @DevAbel Check some of my answers on SO to learn Eloquent.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis your second example worked perfect. Jarek eager loading is little difficult for me to understand, I should learnit. Next can i filter only required columns in these models?  ;-)

Comment: @DevAbel I'd rather not do it when using ORM, but obviously you can use `select`. However mind that you always need to select foreign and primary keys of the relations.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I think I had something else in mind, and that you are indeed true. But it's possible to add clauses to the relationship query as documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: @RonniEgeriis Of course you can add constraints on the eager loading query. Possibilities are pretty much countless, only having in mind that the queries are separate.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$tasks = Task::where(...)->with('customer.staffs')->get();

// then for a given task get collection of staffs by customer:
$tasks->first()->customer->staffs;
```