# Laravel relation between 3 tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have following tables:

1. users (classic laravel table)
2. events
3. user_events

in user_events I insert assigned users to events, the table structure is so:

```
Schema::create('user_events', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to create a page for auth user with his events.

To get Id's I use following relation in Model User:

```
public function userEvents() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserEvent');
}
```

Trought controller I get a list of Event id's.

My previous sources are:
[Laravel relation between 3 models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969458/laravel-relation-between-3-models)

[Laravel 5 relation between 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613786/laravel-5-relation-between-3-tables)

[Laravel Eloquent Relation between 3 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269379/laravel-eloquent-relation-between-3-table)

My question is, what is here to do to get throught this event id's event names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your schema the relation should be [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead of [`one-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

So your relation in `User` model looks as:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Event');
}
```

Then in your controller, get all the events of authenticated user by:

```
$events = auth()->user()->events; // returns collection of Event model
```

Comment: Only to inform other users: I had also a synthax error, there was UserEvent instead of EventUser, after this changes everything works fine :), thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could **[`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck)** the `name` from collection returned by `$user->userEvents` :

```
$user->userEvents->pluck('name');
```

Hope this helps.